# Get all elements that does not contain data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td data-col="firstname">Robert</td>
  <td data-col="middlename">E</td>
  <td data-col="lastname">McIntosh</td>
  <td data-col="email">example@gmail.com</td>
  <td data-col="title" data-id="123456">Programmer</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td data-col="firstname">John</td>
  <td data-col="middlename">M</td>
  <td data-col="lastname">Doe</td>
  <td data-col="email">j.m.doe@gmail.com</td>
  <td data-col="title" data-id="456789">IT Manager</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td data-col="firstname">Sue</td>
  <td data-col="middlename">L</td>
  <td data-col="lastname">Merser</td>
  <td data-col="email">s.l.merser@gmail.com</td>
  <td data-col="title" data-id="789123">Hates Her Job</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add a class labeled `title_hide` to all `td` elements that does not contain the a data attribute id equal to `123456`?

Javascript I am trying:

```
$('table tr td:not([data-id="123456"])').closest('tr').addClass('title_hide');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('td:not([data-id="123456"])').addClass('title_hide');
```

---

**UPDATE:** According to your update it seems that you are trying to add class to `<tr>` element, which doesn't have `<td data-id="123456">` inside. In this case you may use the following approach:

```
$('tr:not(:has(td[data-id="123456"]))').addClass('title_hide');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RFwJg/

Comment: @Alvaro To a noticeable degree when run once?? Doubt it's worth the extra code

Comment: @Alvaro Anyway, check http://jsperf.com/hgfhgsdghsdfg/2 - using the actual selector used here, the `:not` selector is faster. You used a longer selector which makes it less effective.

Comment: @Alvaro You used the wrong code snippet. My code does not search for `<td>` elements inside `<table>`. #SmokeyPHP is right.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$("table tr td:not([data-id=123456])").addClass("title_hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not()

```
 $("td:not('[data-col]')").addClass('title_hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('td').not('td[data-id="123456"]').addClass('title_hide');
    });
</script>
```